# Unwanted replacements from multipass search-and-replace

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

I'm trying to use PHP to replace some item ids in a piece of JSON, and experiencing a problem where the replacements from the first pass are being overwritten by the replacements from the second pass.

```
<?php
$body = "Hello World";
$soul = str_replace(['World', 'Earth'], ['Earth', 'Vietnam'], $body);
echo $soul;
```

Expected: "Hello Earth" Observed "Hello Vietnam"

My situation is more ruthless, since my mappings are numbers to numbers, like "id139"=>"id189" and "id189"=>"id18". How do I do search-and-replace in a big blob of text without risking multiple replacements?

The closest we got to a good solution was something like this:

```
$regPatterns = [
     "/floatingSectionItems-(\d+)-1006/",
     "/floatingSectionItems-(\d+)-160/",
     "/floatingSectionItems-(\d+)-1/",
];
$regReplacements = [
     "goosebumps-160-160",
     "goosebumps-168-168",
     "goosebumps-171-171",
];

$layout = preg_replace($regPatterns, $regReplacements, $layout);
$layout = str_replace(‘goosebumps’, ‘floatingSectionItems’, $layout);
```

While this *works* in this particular case, I feel like there could be solution that doesn't require five passes; like a preg_match_all() followed by a limited str_replace() or a way to parse the original and replace in one pass.

Comment: I think you may need to try to figure out how to build a single pattern regex that can work potentially [with a callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) with your custom replacement logic, so that the pattern isn't processed on previous replacements.

Comment: The trouble with specifying multiple search/replace items is that it is equivalent to just running the function multiple times with single search/replace pairs. If you have items occur in both search and replace items you need to take care to order them in such a way as to not have the replacements replaced. If, in your first example, you reversed the ordering of the search/replace pairs you'd get the desired result. Possibly with the second example as well.

Comment: Scuzzy's suggestion could potentially work as it would perform just a single pass over the input, rather than several potentially-conflicting passes.

Comment: Your example above is just a simple text, but you said in your description that this was about JSON - so why are you messing around with _that_ with string replacement in the first place? Decode it, change what needs changing in the resulting data structure, and then encode it again ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to try to figure out how to build a single pattern regex that can work potentially [with a callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) with your custom replacement logic, so that the pattern isn't processed on previous replacements.

```
    $layout = " blah blah floatingSectionItems-100-200 floatingSectionItems-300-400 blah blah ";

    $layout = preg_replace_callback('/floatingSectionItems-(\d+)-(\d+)/', function($matches){

        if( $matches[1] == '100' and $matches[2] == '200' )
        {
            return 'floatingSectionItems-300-400';
        }

        if( $matches[1] == '300' and $matches[2] == '400' )
        {
            return 'floatingSectionItems-100-200';
        }

        return $matches[0]; // do nothing

    }, $layout);

    echo $layout;
```

you can then build your replacement logic inside of the callback that will work with one item at a time, and never backtrack over already replaced items, in this example I'm flipping the two number patterns around to show it won't conflict.

The capturing groups (brackets) will allow you to work on just the number values of your pattern.

---

In addition, if you wish to inject replacements as an array into your callback you can do this with the function syntax of `use($foo)`

```
    $replacements = [ '100' => '300', '300' => '100' ];

    $layout = preg_replace_callback('/floatingSectionItems-(\d+)-(\d+)/', function($matches) use ($replacements){

        if( isset( $replacements[ $matches[1] ] ) )
            return sprintf('floatingSectionItems-%s-200', $replacements[ $matches[1] ] );

        return $matches[0];

    }, $layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtr()](https://php.net/strtr):

```
$body = "Hello World";
echo strtr(
    $body,
    [
        'World' => 'Earth',
        'Earth' => 'Vietnam'
    ]
);
```

```
Hello Earth
```

> The longest keys will be tried first. Once a substring has been replaced, its new value will not be searched again.